# Firebase dialog won't appear after relogin

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my case, if the user is the teamOwner of that team in the listview, when he long click the team, a dialog will appear. However if he isn't, then nothing will happen. I manage to show the dialog after the user had created the team, but when I logout and login with the same account, even though I am the teamOwner, the dialog won't appear anymore when I long click it. I store user's email as the teamOwner. My code is at below, let me know if you need any more information.

MainActivity:

```
listViewTeams.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Team team = teams.get(i);
            String owner = user.getEmail();

            if (owner == team.getTeamOwner()) {
                showUpdateDeleteDialog(team.getTeamId(), team.getTeamName());
            }
            else{

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

AddActitvity:

```
private void addTeam() {
    //getting the values to save
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String sport = spinnerSport.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String date = textDate.getText().toString();
    String time = textTime.getText().toString();

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    user.getEmail();

    //checking if the value is provided
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

        //getting a unique id using push().getKey() method
        //it will create a unique id and we will use it as the Primary Key for our Team
        String id = databaseTeams.push().getKey();
        String owner = user.getEmail();
        String member = user.getEmail();

        //creating an Team Object
        Team team = new Team(id, name, sport, owner, date, time);
        Member members = new Member(member);

        //Saving the Team
        databaseTeams.child(name).setValue(team);
        databaseMembers.child(name).setValue(members);

        //setting edittext to blank again
        editTextName.setText("");

        //displaying a success toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Team added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        //if the value is not given displaying a toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Team.java

```
public class Team {
private String teamId;
private String teamName;
private String teamSport;
private String teamOwner;
private String date;
private String time;

public Team() {

}

public Team(String teamId, String teamName, String teamSport, String teamOwner, String date, String time) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.teamSport = teamSport;
    this.teamOwner = teamOwner;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}

public String getTeamId() {return teamId;}

public  String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public String getTeamSport() {
    return teamSport;
}

public String getTeamOwner() { return  teamOwner; }

public String getDate(){ return date; }

public String getTime() { return time; }

}
```

Database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found the solution to my problem. In my main activity, I use '==' instead of .equals() which is not recommended.

Refer here:
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)